# How to isolate object property where object is state in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have an object with an object inside and array as a state in my component.

```
const [courseAndUserIDs, setCourseAndUserIDs] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:8080/courses/${id}`)
            .then(resp => resp.json())
            .then(data => setCourseAndUserIDs(data))
            .catch(err => setIsErr(true));
    }, [])
```

This state is set after the component is mounted. This state looks like this:

```
State
:
{course: {…}, userIDs: Array(4)}

course
:
{averageRating: 3, categories: Array(3), comments: …}

userIDs
:
[2, 5, 1, 6]
```

Now every time I want to get a property from a `course` object I have to type this: `courseAndUserIDs.course.property` I want to shorten this entry. How can I do this ?

Remember that effects created using useEffect are run after the render commit phase and hence after the render cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to define an intermediate variable `const courses = courseAndUserIDs.course`.

You can also find a shorter name than `courseAndUserIds`. The word "and" in a variable name seems like a code smell to me.

Alternatively, you can separate the state:

```
const courses, setCourses = useState();
const users, setUsers = useState();
```

Comment: separating the state won't affect on performance? I mean: when I call `setCourses` and `setUser` in my `useEffect`, my application will render twice or still only once?

Comment: @Monoxyd That's a good question. I'm new to `useState()` and `useEffect()`. I don't know what impact this will have on rendering. My suggestion is try it and see.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think your comment here merits a separate answer. Particularly explaining how to use destructuring syntax here.

Comment: @Monoxyd - Just to replace the part of the comment that didn't go in my answer: It's absolutely fine to call two state setters from `useState` in a row (`setCourse(x); setUsers(x);`). It doesn't cause two separate renders. React batches things up. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I like the approach from [Code-Apprentice's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68896388/157247) and that's what I would probably do (depending on specifics), but if you don't want to do that for any reason (maybe the state member is always updated monolithically and just "feels" like one thing; or maybe style reasons), an alternative is to destructure the state member into a couple of local constants for convenience, something like this:

```
const [courseAndUserIDs, setCourseAndUserIDs] = useState(null);
const {course, userIDs} = courseAndUserIDs ?? {};
```

The object shown there is only created if `courseAndUserIDs` is "nullish" (`null` or `undefined`). (Details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator).)

In that specific case, `course` and `userIDs` will be `undefined` if `courseAndUserIDs` is `null`, but you can spin it a few ways depending on what's most useful. For instance, if `null` and an empty array were more useful, you could supply destructuring default values:

```
const [courseAndUserIDs, setCourseAndUserIDs] = useState(null);
const {course = null, userIDs = []} = courseAndUserIDs ?? {};
```

As with the object initializer earlier, that array is only created if `courseAndUserIDs` is `null` or undefined or if `courseAndUserIDs.userIDs` is `undefined`.

Or if you **only** want defaults when `courseAndUserIDs` is nullish but you want `undefined` if `courseAndUserIDs.userIDs` is `undefined`, you might put those values in the object that's only used when `courseAndUserIDs` is nullish:

```
const [courseAndUserIDs, setCourseAndUserIDs] = useState(null);
const {course, userIDs} = courseAndUserIDs ?? {course: null, userIDs: []};
```

Whichever works best for you in any specific case.